# How to send emails hosted in zoho mail via laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have developed a web application to send and store company daily reports using laravel.I have setup my configuration in the mail.php file of the application.Once the report is submitted an email is sent to the CEO and vice versa.

It is sending email notification to all other emails like gmail and yahoo but no emails are sent for the company emails such as example @example.com which are hosted in zoho mail,giving me an error "connection to zoho failed "

Please help,thanks in advance

Comment: Show your configuration. Zoho requires you to use a SSL connection to their IMAP server.

Comment: In my config file the encryption type I changed from tls to ssl but not working

Answer (score 0):

When I integrate Zoho configuration in laravel, I've faced few difficulties to set the configuration as it's quite confusing what should be the MAIL_USERNAME or MAIL_PASSWORD or even MAIL_HOST
Here is the guideline I've followed to set the configuration

- MAIL_USERNAME: this should be the email address of your Zoho account
- MAIL_PASSWORD: you need to generate the password from the security menu of Zoho dashboard
  Security > App Passwords > Generate New Password
- MAIL_HOST: this is very important, wherever I've searched the MAIL_HOST was always smtp.zoho.com but since my Zoho account was in the Indian region I need to use the smtp.zoho.in instead of com so make sure you used the correct domain host